# Predicting Survey Response Rates

Tags: r, machine-learning, tensorflow, statistics

I'm trying to predict the response rate for a course evaluation given several data points:

1. Class size
2. Previous Instructor Ratings (numerical)
3. Discussion Section Size
4. Grade level the class is meant for

I'm trying to figure out a way to construct a prediction model that will output an expected response rate given a set of these input variables. I've looked into TensorFlow and Independent Component Analysis, but I'm not sure if they are the most appropriate for the task at hand.

Does anyone have some suggestions for algorithms (machine learning or otherwise), that I could implement to create this model?

Thanks

Comment: Why not start with something simple such as regression? Which type of regression depends on the data, you'll need to give more info on that (what are your units; how many data points;...; a sample of your data if possible); poisson regression probably in this case. However, you are asking on the wrong location as you are not asking for code. This question belongs on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a linear model where response is explained by those variables.

E.g. `lm_Eric <- lm(response ~ class + instructor + discussion + grade)`

The estimates for your coefficients would be shown in `summary(lm_Eric)`